# Modifying the FitzHugh-Nagumo model so it generates spikes with long duration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I want to modify the FitzHugh-Nagumo model, possibly by changing its parameters, so that instead of spikes with brief duration, it generates spikes with long duration, i.e. a prolonged plateau shape potential (something that resembles a rectangle) which last for a couple of hundred milliseconds.
Any ideas?

Comment: You mean long duration relative to the periodicity? And what exactly are you interested in? Just a function with certain features, or is it important to you that it is the solution to a certain kind of ODE (similar to the FHN model)?

Comment: Yes, long-duration relative to the periodicity. However, I don't want the system to oscillate. Instead, I want it to be excitable, i.e. it receives multiple brief stimulations, and when it reaches a certain threshold, it produces a plateau shape spike, then it should return to the resting state.

Comment: @Hamsadeh Do you want both coordinates to have plateau-shape or just one of them? If both have plateau-shape on some time interval, it indicates that you are coming quite close to a saddle equilibrium. If only one has plateau-shape, you are coming close to some part of slow manifold. These are just only general ideas for what you should look for in your system to have such kind of behavior.